# the best offline database for mobile

Tags: database, react-native

I made a complete app using firebase, expo and react native (with login screen and other features). But it didn't work as I expected because I need an app that the database works offline (I want the user to use the app offline, and then connect to the internet and "update" the data).
In other words, I'm looking for another way. I heard about Realm, but it doesn't work with Expo (from what I've researched). Can anyone guide me to some possibilities??

About the app I'm making: login>selection>release

*the user logs in (offline. The first time can be online, but when entering the app again, the login must be OFFLINE). The next screen is 'selection' (all screens show information of the logged in user), the user writes some information that is saved in a database. When completing the 'selection', the next screen is 'release', in which the user will add information in the same data table (db) before (from the 'selection' screen). The user will not have internet when entering the app (but he can access the internet later and update his data as soon as he connects).

Comment: https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/async-storage/

Comment: async storage is not a database  Why would you link that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into watermelonDb. It uses SQLite under the hood and is offline-first.

As some commenters in the previous answer pointed out, firebase has offline capabilities, but is probably a bait for most people because it doesn't persist offline changes when the user closes the app.

If you are certain your local database won't require any complex querying (sorting, ordering, etc.) or any other advanced SQL feature, then you can get away with storing all your data in AsyncStorage, which is only good for getting and setting key/value pairs, nothing else.

Hope that helps! If any new library pops up since this answer, leave a mention in the comments below.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase work offline and import the data when it is online.

Now about the other db that works with expo, if you like working with SQL then there is something I built [expo-sqlite-wrapper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/expo-sqlite-wrapper) it is a good ORM and did not find any better.

There is also a JSON based database [easy-db-react-native](https://www.npmjs.com/package/easy-db-react-native), the downside of this is that you can't have too much data saved.

Comment: Firebase offline functionality is bad for my app (they're great, but not what I'm looking for). In firebase offline it is not possible to restart the app and the data is still there. I will look into these links, thank you very much for the reply.

Comment: there's always a cache when it comes to firebase services. Their products and services extremely often fit simple uses cases, but are lacking in features otherwise.